# Reconfigure line-in as analog-out

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sound-card, alsa, pulse-audio

I am trying to reconfigure my "line in" as another "analog out" and use it alongside with the default analog out port.

I am using an onboard realtek sound card. It is very simple to do this in windows with driver gui but couldn't find a way to do it in linux.

Comment: Related to [Can I make the Audio In port function as a Audio Out port?](http://superuser.com/questions/613224/can-i-make-the-audio-in-port-as-a-audio-out-port)

Comment: You might receive better answers to this over at www.linuxquestions.org if you haven't posted it there already.

Comment: @PaulHay I did not. I will also try there, thanks.

Comment: @Scott that is for windows.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/613224/can-i-make-the-audio-in-port-as-a-audio-out-port

Comment: @Taegost mine is supported by my hardware as I can do it on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just manage to do this on my laptopt, using the mic input instead of line-in.

I did it by following the steps on this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output)

I just had to download HDA Analyzer and run it as root:

```
wget -O run.py http://www.alsa-project.org/hda-analyzer.py
sudo python run.py
```

Locate the right PIN node (more details about it on askubuntu) uncheck IN and check OUT.

Click on export to save a python script that will make this same changes when run, then add it somwhere on your startup scripts.

I manage to get sound out of my mic jack, but it wasn't pretty. You'll probably have it better since you're using line-in instead of mic.

Comment: There are some issues about pygtk in that script for Arch, but managed to get it work and did the job.

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/hda-analyzer.py gives "404 Not Found", but you can still access the git tree here https://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa.git;a=tree;f=hda-analyzer