# Can I make the Audio In port as a Audio Out port?

Tags: windows-7, audio

My [motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4N68TM_LE_V2/#specifications) has a VIA chipset ( VIA VT1708S 8-Channel High Definition Audio CODEC *1)

Can this be done if so how ?

Comment: I rolled back to the original edit, due to the change was more of an answer/comment, rather than adding more detail to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, such as this case, it's not physically possible.  The issue is with the hardware, the way the amplifiers, rectifiers, and other -iers are setup, they only take audio in from those ports, and that can't be reversed.

Comment: That is unless the hardware device supports switching that port.  I had an old Compaq laptop that could do this, presumably to save space while still keeping the functionality.

Comment: True, I guess I should say that 99% of the time it's not physically possible since it's not something that's done very often.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation on this chipset; It seems that it's a definite "No" regarding the back ports, but port reassignment might be possible with the front audio ports; Make sure you have the driver installed (including any VIA utilities for managing the audio chip) and see if it pops up and asks you what you plugged into the system when you plug a device into the front audio.

If you're asking about turning the microphone (pink) or line-in (blue) port on the back into a second front speakers out or a rear speakers out, then no, the chipset does not do that.